# Can't connect WiFi after upgrade from 16 to 18

Tags: 18.04, wireless

After upgrade my WiFi module suddenly become disabled. Please help me to figure out the issue source. Thanks!

Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

```
iwconfig 

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on


lshw -C network
  *-usb DISABLED            
       description: Wireless interface
       product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
       vendor: VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 2.05
       serial: 00:12:7b:46:2b:07
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vt6656                               

      driverversion=4.15.0-62-generic firmware=N/A link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11


cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
# auto eth0
# iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0

cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml

cat: '/etc/netplan/*.yaml': No such file or directory

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

sudo lshw -C network
  *-usb DISABLED            
       description: Wireless interface
       product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
       vendor: VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 2.05
       serial: 00:12:7b:46:2b:07
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vt6656 driverversion=4.15.0-62-generic firmware=N/A link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: MCP77 Ethernet
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: a
       bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: a2
       serial: 10:bf:48:bb:ea:a9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm msi ht bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 duplex=full ip=10.0.0.101 latency=0 link=yes maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:fe02b000-fe02bfff ioport:d800(size=8) memory:fe02a000-fe02a0ff memory:fe029000-fe02900f
```

Comment: Could you post the output of `rfkill list`?

Comment: rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and also: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Your file `/etc/network/interfaces` is malformed. In order for Network Manager to manage your wireless, the malformed entry must be removed. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

Remove entirely the line `auto wlan0`. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit nano (Ctrl+x).

Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Does Network Manager now see wireless networks and offer to connect?

I would also like to know if netplan is installed and running. Please post:

```
ls -al /etc/netplan
```

**EDIT**: Let's recreate the needed netplan file and see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/netplan
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following text:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc. Please use spaces, not tabs. Proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Is there any improvement? Does the interface still reports as Disabled?

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

It might take a reboot.

Comment: I fixed /etc/network/interfaces but it didn't help. I have no netplan installed.

Comment: Is the device still shown as disabled? `sudo lshw -C network` Why do you believe netplan is not installed? It is standard in Ubuntu 18.04. Please show: `sudo updatedb && locate netplan` Does the command return dozens of items or no items at all? Please post: `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e vt6`

Comment: It looks like a problem in theloading of the driver module: dmesg | grep -e wlan -e vt6 
[   35.868433] vt6656_stage: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   35.868549] vt6656_stage: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   36.156534] usbcore: registered new interface driver vt6656
[   64.689561] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: It was shown in apt to be installed. But now netplan is there: sudo updatedb && locate netplan
/etc/init.d/netplan
/etc/plan/netplan-acl
.... too long output for this comment Output of sudo netplan command is empty.

Comment: Please show: `ls -al /etc/netplan`

Comment: ls -al /etc/netplan
ls: cannot access '/etc/netplan': No such file or directory

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: sudo netplan apply
returns with error: bind: Address already in use
netplan: fatal error: cannot bind to port 2983, is another daemon running?, exiting.

Comment: root@timathome:/home/blok# sudo lshw -C network
  *-usb DISABLED            
       description: Wireless interface
       product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
       vendor: VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 2.05
       serial: 00:12:7b:46:2b:07
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vt6656 driverversion=4.15.0-64-generic firmware=N/A link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11

Comment: cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml 
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

Comment: ps -ax | grep netplan
 6212 ?        Ss     0:00 netplan generate

Comment: I mixed up netplan planning tool with netplan configuration tool you were talking about. Fixed that with apt install netplan.io netplan- and then netplan generate and netplan apply commands with reboot. It did not help: iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr=2346 B   
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

Comment: sudo lshw -C network
  *-usb DISABLED            
       description: Wireless interface
       product: VNT USB-802.11 Wireless LAN Adapter
       vendor: VIA Networking Technologies, Inc.
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@1:5
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 2.05
       serial: 00:12:7b:46:2b:07
       capabilities: usb-2.00 ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=vt6656 driverversion=4.15.0-64-generic firmware=N/A link=no maxpower=500mA multicast=yes speed=480Mbit/s wireless=IEEE 802.11

Comment: cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

Comment: Let's have a look at: `dmesg | grep -e wlan -e vt6` As the output may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: It is quite short, the driver did not start: sudo dmesg | grep -e wlan -e vt6
[   33.003440] vt6656_stage: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   33.003550] vt6656_stage: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   33.296683] usbcore: registered new interface driver vt6656
[   62.249075] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready

Comment: The driver started perfectly well. Something in your system setting the interface to *Disabled*. We just haven't found it yet. Let's see: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i netplan` and also: cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork` Again, use the paste link above.

Comment: sudo su
[sudo] password for blok: 
root@timathome:/home/blok/Telegram# cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i netplan
Sep 22 10:54:23 timathome systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Netplan calendar service....
Sep 22 10:54:24 timathome netplan[1597]: Netplan daemon not enabled in /etc/init.d/netplan.
Sep 22 10:54:24 timathome systemd[1]: Started LSB: Netplan calendar service..

Comment: The second request was quite big, so it is there: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/9zBDRJshs9/